# How to change the innodb_lru_scan_depth value on Google SQL Cloud?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

On one of our instance we're getting this kind of error:

```
2017-01-11T11:12:48.513497Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 5745ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=614 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

The error begin a big series of the same everytime it popups in the logs and in a case, due to coincidental other events, caused the instance to be unresponsive for a long time.

Now one of the suggestion given from the community support board was to change the setting of `innodb_lru_scan_depth` lowering it from the default 1024 to 256.

I checked in the mysql instance flags and cannot see it so I tried accessing the instance directly and running this:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lru_scan_depth=256;
```

Unfortunately without the `SUPER` privilege we cannot change that settings.

```
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

How should I change that value then? Is there any other way I'm not aware of?

Also, I'm aware that changing that setting is not really going to be the "solution" as that means that we're running queries too heavy for the hardware. The reason for that is that those queries are run once per month and it's not really worth to upgrade the instance's hardware just for that.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done under super privileges like:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lru_scan_depth=256;
```

Basically, it has to be done when server is not in active mode.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, we cannot set global variables like `innodb_lru_scan_depth`

CloudSQL doesn't accept that, because your `root` account is not the real root.

We only have permission on list of variables (flags) based on https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/flags

Answer (score 0):

These can be set via the CloudSQL UI:

[image]